# Unpacking NSPack v 2.9 based malware to get OEP

Tags: obfuscation, unpacking

recently i am analyzing a malware which is packed with NSPack.
when i am trying to unpack it using this [blog link](https://evilcodecave.wordpress.com/tag/backdoorwin32rbot/),i landed over two instruction `PUSHFD,PUSHAD` in ollydbg.
so i put a breakpoint on the jmp instruction which will do unpack

```
004DF425                       9D              POPFD
004DF426                      -E9 A5D4FFFF     JMP 5df0b1b0.004DC8D0
```

after stepover, i have landed over below instruction which is not start of a pe file

```
004DC8D0                         60            DB 60                               ;  CHAR '`'
004DC8D1                         BE            DB BE
004DC8D2                         00            DB 00
004DC8D3                         20            DB 20                               ;  CHAR ' '
004DC8D4                         4C            DB 4C                               ;  CHAR 'L'
004DC8D5                         00            DB 00
004DC8D6                         8D            DB 8D
004DC8D7                         BE            DB BE
004DC8D8                         00            DB 00
004DC8D9                         F0            DB F0
004DC8DA                         F3            DB F3
004DC8DB                         FF            DB FF
004DC8DC                         57            DB 57                               ;  CHAR 'W'
004DC8DD                         83            DB 83
004DC8DE                         CD            DB CD
```

the above instruction is very strange
i should expect instruction like

```
PUSH EBP
PUSH EBP,ESP
```

so how can i unpack the malware and where i am wrong during unpacking.Help will be appreciated
Hash of malware:`59c661ba0c7c485f4480f7b142a9c084`

Comment: You need to right-click on those bytes in the disassembly pane and select `Analysis → Remove analysis from module`. See [Ollydbg - Remove analysis from module](http://reverseengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/6889/ollydbg-remove-analysis-from-module) and [Ollydbg Instructions Are Splitted](http://reverseengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/8693/ollydbg-instructions-are-splitted).

Comment: Thanks JasonGeffner for the help.but even after doing "Remove analysis",i still can't reach OEP.

Answer (score 2):

The blog post to which you linked has incorrect information. `0x004DC8D0` is not the OEP. Rather, `0x0041A4E3` is the OEP.

After reaching `0x004DC8D0`, right-click on the machine code in the disassembly pane and select `Analysis → Remove analysis from module`. Then scroll down a bit to `0x004DCA84`; you'll see there's a `JMP` from that address to `0x0041A4E3`, which is the correct OEP:

[image: JMP to OEP]

Comment: HI Jason,even after following (Remove code analysis from module),i got these instructions 004DC8D0      60                PUSHAD
004DC8D1      BE 00204C00       MOV ESI,5df0b1b0.00>
004DC8D6      8DBE 00F0F3FF     LEA EDI,DWORD PTR [>
004DC8DC      57                PUSH EDI
004DC8DD      83CD FF           OR EBP,FFFFFFFF
004DC8E0      EB 10             JMP SHORT 5df0b1b0.>
004DC8E2      90                NOP
004DC8E3      90                NOP
004DC8E4      90                NOP
004DC8E5      90                NOP
004DC8E6      90                NOP
004DC8E7      90                NOP

Comment: And also if i am going 0041A4E3,i am viewing these instruction which is not seems to be a start of a PE file.0041A4E3               0000            ADD BYTE PTR [EAX],AL
0041A4E5               0000            ADD BYTE PTR [EAX],AL
0041A4E7               0000            ADD BYTE PTR [EAX],AL
0041A4E9               0000            ADD BYTE PTR [EAX],AL
etc

Comment: You have to let the code execute until `0x0041A4E3` is reached.

Comment: Thanks @jason .i got the instruction 0041A4E3             >  55            PUSH EBP
0041A4E4             ?  8BEC          MOV EBP,ESP
0041A4E6             ?  6A FF         PUSH -1

Comment: Great, feel free to accept my answer then.

Answer (score 0):

[image]
so ollydbg didn't understand the code put unnecessary code.so after doing "Remove analysis" from the assembly pane i got OEP
Now NS based packed got unpacked
Thanks @jason Geffner